# Tell QGIS to use the installed GDAL through homebrew on Mac

Tags: gdal, homebrew

I have had lots trouble with the gdal_fillnodata on my Mac running Monterey (12.6.5) on any QGIS version (tried multiple). I always got a horrible fill as a result, tried everything, deleting QGIS, reinstalling using the newest version instead of the LTR - nothing helped. Then I downloaded GDAL through homebrew and ran it directly in the terminal and it worked perfectly.

The version that I downloaded through brew was way newer (3.6.4) than the one installed with the newest QGIS release (3.3.2). Why isn't the newest version of gdal included in the Mac release? Can I somehow tell QGIS to use the gdal scripts that I have installed into /usr/local so I don't have to use the terminal every time to fill my DTMs? Or can I just copy them into the QGIS Resources folder?

QGIS version
3.32.0-Lima

QGIS code revision
b9862de816

Qt version
5.15.2

Python version
3.9.5

GDAL/OGR version
3.3.2

PROJ version
8.1.1

EPSG Registry database version
v10.028 (2021-07-07)

GEOS version
3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2

SQLite version
3.35.2

PDAL version
2.3.0

PostgreSQL client version
unknown

SpatiaLite version
5.0.1

QWT version
6.1.6

QScintilla2 version
2.11.5

OS version
macOS 12.6

Active Python plugins

FreehandRasterGeoreferencer 0.8.3

quick_map_services 0.19.33

nominatim
1.4.5

LAStools
1.4

SRTM-Downloader
3.1.17

ViewshedAnalysis
1.8

QGIS-terrain-shading-master
0.9.4

Generalizer3
1.0

qgis-maptiler-plugin
3.2

processing
2.12.99

grassprovider
2.12.99

db_manager
0.1.20

MetaSearch
0.3.6